# youtube API bug with video id's that begin with a dash

Tags: youtube-data-api

Here is an example video from youtube with a video id that starts with a dash:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jjBiDk7VRg

If I go to that url in a browser the video loads.

However, if i try to query that video id via the api, I get a response back, but the response doesn't have the `snippet` object that I am expecting.

Here is the request I'm making:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUTUBE_API_KEY}q=-jjBiDk7VRg&part=snippet&maxResults=1&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true`

And the response i get back is:

```
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"j6xRRd8dTPVVptg711_CSPADRfg/uKsXaflsfl5lEpI1-3fl383VQyo\"",
  "regionCode": "US",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": []
}
```

Strange thing is, if I remove the dash from the video Id and query it, the response has the `snippet` object i want.  But if I try to remove the dash and from the youtube and try to see the video on the browser, i.e. go to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjBiDk7VRg, it fails.  Webpage says video unavailable.

This looks like a bug in youtube v3 api.

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/jcyl29/pen/QWwwgXy

Comment: What is your question, exactly? If it's just a bug report, you should send it to Google, not post it here.

Comment: yes it was mistake to post it here, i'll send it to the issue tracker, thanks

Comment: I know this comment is off-topic, but why are you querying a video ID with the Search API instead of the Video GET API? Searching for the video ID yields no results on the YouTube site, which would be expected as for the results returned.

Answer (score 0):

The dash is used as an operator for q parameter which when used will exclude videos. The workaround is to surround it with double quotes e.g. "-jjBiDk7VRg".  In other words, the GET request will end up looking like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%22-jjBiDk7VRg%22&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

As an aside, if the videoId is known, it is more efficient to use the video/list API instead of search/list.  Then no enclosing with quotes is needed.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the dash from the video ID and it will work fine. Don't ask me why YT suddenly adds this dash in front of some IDs. But removing it gives the correct API reply.